# Different ways to set value for a event parameter/ parameters

Tags: event, javascript-controller

In the salesforce official doc- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_event.htm I see two ways to set value for event parameters.

1)`event.setParam("name", cmp.get("v.myName");` - For single parameters

2) `event.setParams({key : value });` - For multiple parameters (For object attributes' etc)

However in below controller **event.setParams work but event.setParam doesn't**

```
({
    onBoatClick : function(component, event, helper) {
      var BoatSelectEvent = component.getEvent("BoatSelect");
      var boatSelected = component.get("v.boat.Id");
      BoatSelectEvent.setParams(
          {"boatId" : boatSelected});
      BoatSelectEvent.fire();

    }
})
```

Shouldn't event.setParam set value here?

Comment: Did you use correct syntax ? : event.setParam("name", cmp.get("v.myName");

Comment: My bad. I was using the syntax - event.setParams("name", cmp.get("v.myName");  -which was incorrect.

Comment: Please select the answer so that it will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use correct syntax**

```
 event.setParam("name", cmp.get("v.myName");
```